# Retrieving Profiles and connections - Parameter missing?

Tags: c#, .net, google-people-api

I use Google's .NET people API (v.1.25) and follow the documentation (https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people).

Under

> Retrieve Profiles and Connections
>
> Get the user's connections

for .NET the documentation gives this example code snippet:

```
PeopleResource.ConnectionsResource.ListRequest peopleRequest =
    peopleService.People.Connections.List("people/me");
peopleRequest.PersonFields = "names,emailAddresses";
ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = peopleRequest.Execute();
IList<Person> connections = connectionsResponse.Connections;
```

But **PersonFields** do not exist in the class ListRequest - nor does it exist in GetRequest as the doc suggests in the next example.

Do I misunderstand something or is there a fault in the docs or in the API?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using an old version of the library. If you browse the .NET documentation from the [Install Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/libraries) page it shows the version is `1.5.1`.

If you browse to the [`ConnectionsResource.ListRequest`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1PeopleService_1_1v1_1_1PeopleResource_1_1ConnectionsResource_1_1ListRequest.html) documentation it shows that `PersonFields` exists.

Comment: Your link points to the Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1 namespace. I use Google.Apis.People.v1 - which is what the docu says (follow the link in my post) one should use. Is the People namespace obsolete and only the namespace PeopleService should be used?

Comment: did this work for you?  I adjusted my package to 1.5.1 and dotnet restore dropped me all the way back to 1.10

Answer (score -1):

Just use .Fields instead of .PersonFields. Also I had to declare the entire package name (Google.Apis.People.v1.). Example below.

```
Google.Apis.People.v1.People.PeopleService peopleService;
Google.Apis.People.v1.PeopleResource.ConnectionsResource.ListRequest peopleRequest = peopleService.People.Connections.List("people/me");
    peopleRequest.Fields = "names,emailAddresses";
                        ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = peopleRequest.Execute();
                        IList<Google.Apis.People.v1.Data.Person> connections = connectionsResponse.Connections;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it appears that the Fields property ultimately describes the MethodName, rather than the personFields in 1.25.830